# Procedure on adding image pixel data in a file in newline?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

k=[]
file1=open("TextData.txt",'w')
fn=input("Enter filename : ")
img=cv2.imread(fn,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
l=len(img) 
w=len(img[0]) 
print(str(l)+"\n"+str(w))
for i in range(len(img)):
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        k.append(img[i,j])

for a in range(len[k]):
    file1.write(str(k[a])+"\n")

file1.close()
```

Basically, I'm running into the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "imagereads.py", line 17, in <module>
for a in range(len[k]):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm trying to write a program that will store each image data in a file and access that later on when needed. Can anyone help me in this ? I'm doing this so that I can directly use file1.readLines() to read each data later on.

At first I tried appending each element to k, converting to a string and storing it directly. But I'm having problems getting back the data from the file into a list. Any help on this matter too will be appreciated.

Comment: `len[k]` should have been `len(k)`

Comment: Thanks. That was a silly mistake on my part. I rectified it.